# Magento 1.9.4.2 reset password not working

Tags: magento-upgrade, forgot-password

I updated my website from 1.8.1.0 to 1.9.4.2

When a customer tries to reset their password the following error occurs:

Invalid method Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::changeResetPasswordLinkCustomerId(Array ( [0] => 357371f4c2ad1a03dd768e865dc63b1a ) )

Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Check if there is any custom Module Overwriting the Customer Model `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` If there is double if the above method is defined on that Module as well, if not copy the definition from the core file and define it from that custom module.